# How can I override a gem file in order to access it from my engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overriding, rails-engines

I'm using Devise on a Rails engine and I would like to override a specific file, namely: `lib/devise/controller/helpers.rb`.

I tried to place it into `myengine/lib/devise/controller/helpers.rb` but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I override that file in order to access from my engine? It'd be great if I could do it on a normal Rails app as well (I can figure out the rest myself)

The purpose is to debug that piece of code. See [this issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally put them into initializers just so that I know explicitly that I monkey patched them:

#### example overriding `signed_in_root_path` method:

```
# initializers/devise_controllers_helpers_patch.rb

module Devise
  module Controllers
    module Helpers
      def signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
        puts 'THIS IS MY OWN CODE'
        puts 1 + 1 == 2

        scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
        router_name = Devise.mappings[scope].router_name

        home_path = "#{scope}_root_path"

        context = router_name ? send(router_name) : self

        if context.respond_to?(home_path, true)
          context.send(home_path)
        elsif context.respond_to?(:root_path)
          context.root_path
        elsif respond_to?(:root_path)
          root_path
        else
          "/"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```